# How to write Robots.txt for this links wordpress for stopping them access "page.php?lougout"

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

Hi i have a word press website i did some tweaks.somehow goggle bot showing lots page crawling errors . errors mentioned below.

Error page links example are

**URL Errors**

```
  page3/wp-login.php?action=logout
   page2/wp-login.php?action=logout
   page1z/wp-login.php?action=logout
   ... to n pages
```

i used this robot.txt code

```
Disallow: /logout/
```

but its now working .

Comment: Of course it’s not working, since the requested URLs do not match that path one bit …

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `User-agent: *` at the beginning. This is how my robots.txt looks like. Google does not read them for my site

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /feed/
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

But looking your error log, it looks like it might not be Google or any good crawler. Bad crawlers, don't care about `robots.txt`. What you can do is adding some page into your robots.txt as Disallow and log information like (IP blocks, user agent and header) from crawlers (like a honeypot) and you can then ban them like this

```
order allow,deny
deny from xx.xxx.xx.xx
deny from yy.yy.yyy.yy
deny from zzz.zz.z.zz
allow from all
```

Or a nice redirect to a non-existent site like this,

```
#bad bots
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BadBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EvilBotr [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FakeBot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://byecrawler.com/ #non-existent site
```